# Updating a field which is a lookup on ather custom objects

Tags: apex, custom-object, class, code

**UPDATE 3**
Here is my complete code I have so far;

I have trigger on `vendor__c` object

```
  trigger vendorTrigger on vendor__c (after insert, after update) 
  {
    vendorController vencont = new  vendorController();
    vencont.PopulateWorkOrderBy(Trigger.new);
  }

public with sharing class vendorController
{       
      public void PopulateWorkOrderBy(List<vendor__c> vendor)
      {
         //run some business rules/validations

         //insert into WO
         Work_Order__c wo = new Work_Order__c();
         wo.Est_Hours__c = 89;
         wo.Instructions__c = 'this is a test';
         insert wo; 

         //lets get the vendor id first:
         string venId
         for(vendor__c ven : vendor)
         {
           //get the vendor id
           venId = ven.Id;
         }

         //its time to update the vendor field
         Vendor__c vendorObj = [select Id, Name, current_work_order__c from vendor__c where id =: venId];
         vendorObj.Current_work_order__c = wo.Name //name of the newly created work_order__c Name

         //update the vendor object now
         update vendorObj;
      }
}
```

**END UPDATE**

More explanation:

As I have mentioned the two objects, I will try to walk you guys through the pages:

So you click on the `Vendor` page and pick the existing record or create a new  record, let say if creating a new record:

I'm on `Vendor page` click on `New`

Entered all the information related to that object and once you click on `save`  you will perform the following operation:

```
1) save the Vendor data
2) create a new entry in `work_order__c` object
3) copy the created `work_order__c` Id/Name to the `Vendor` fields in this case it will be ``Current_Work_Order__c'
```

**END UPDATE**

I have already spent hour trying to figured out and I think I need some help here.

I have two custom objects:

1) work_order__c
2) vendor__c

in my `work_order__c` object I have the following fields:

```
Name (Auto number)
Est_Hours__c
Instructions__c
Status__c
```

in my `vendor__c` object I have to following fields:

```
Name (Auto number)
Current_Work_Order__c (lookup to work_order__c object)
Status__c
```

What I'm trying to do is simple when I create a `work_order__c` record I want to grab the newly created work order and placed in the `vendor__c` object `current_work_order__c`

I'm not getting along ... below is my code:

```
//insert into WO
Work_Order__c wo = new Work_Order__c();
wo.Est_Hours__c = 89;
wo.Instructions__c = 'this is a test';
insert wo;
```

//inserted successfully (checked with debug)

now I'm trying to copy the name of the `work_order__c` to `current_work_order__c` remember its a lookup relationship.

here is what i'm doing:

```
vendor__c vendor_obj = [select Id,Name,Current_Work_Order__c from vendor__c where Id =: wo.id limit 1];
vendor_obj.Current_Work_Order__c = wo.id;
update vendor_obj;
```

What I'm doing wrong here? and I have also tried using `wo.Name` did not work either.

Comment: You are querying the ID of Vendor__c, but you are using the Work_Order__c Id to query it. 

Does the Vendor__c sObject already exist?  Are you trying to reparent it from one Work_Order__c to another?  Or are you trying to create a new Vendor__c for each Work_Order__c?

Comment: Yes the vendor object is already exists, from vendor I am creating work order and updating the vendor current work order... Hope it make sense

Comment: Are you creating a Work_Order__c record from a trigger of Vendor__c? Explain "from vendor I am creating work order" in your above comment

Comment: How do you know how which `vendor__c` object is related to this `work_order__c` record? You're trying to query the vendor record based on the work order's ID. That ain't gonna work.

Comment: I have updated my question and try to explain little bit more

Comment: Can you share the code of saving the vendor from the page? That would help us give you a working solution you can use.

Comment: Nav: I am not using any custom code to save the vendor I am using the standard save option

Comment: Abu, if you need custom functionality (like creating another type of record before saving) you need to override your Save button with custom code.  Where do you have the code to create new Work_Order__c now? Another option is to have a trigger to do this work every time a new Vender__c is created or updated.

Comment: Yes I am calling trigger to my apex class and  I have no power here  so I can not paste the code I Am on my phone replying you.

Comment: you should query your vendor__c better. now its finding all vendors and you assign work_order__c randomly without any logic. try to simulate your Trigger on consule /debug and see whats happens...

Comment: There are a couple issues with your Trigger as you have it written.  1.  You will experience trigger recursion by updatnig Vendor in an "after insert" "after update" trigger, you should make it a "before insert" "before update" trigger.  2. Your trigger is not Bulkified.  As it is written now, if more than one "Vendor" object were to be inserted or updated at the same time you would only create one Work Order object, and it would only be assigned to the last Vendor object.  @navD87's solution looks to be the closest to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a trigger on Vendor__c, you can achieve this as following,

```
trigger updateWorkOrder on Vendor__c (before insert, before update) {

    List<Work_Order__c> workOrdersToInsert = new List<Work_Order__c>();
    List<Vendor__c> vendorsWithoutWorkOrders = new List<Vendor__c>();
    Work_Order__c wo;
    for(Vendor__c v : Trigger.new) {
        if(v.Current_Work_Order__c == null) {
            vendorsWithoutWorkOrders.add(v);
            wo = new Work_Order__c();
            wo.Est_Hours__c = 89;
            wo.Instructions__c = 'this is a test';  
            workOrdersToInsert.add(wo);
        }
    }
    insert workOrdersToInsert;

    for(Integer i=0; i<vendorsWithoutWorkOrders.size(); i++) {
        vendorsWithoutWorkOrders.get(i).Current_Work_Order__c = workOrdersToInsert.get(i).Id;
    }

}
```

Comment: please have a look at the update 3 I just updated.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes the vendor object is already exists, from vendor I am creating work order and updating the vendor current work order...

If the Vendor already exists, and you have it referenced in code, you could do something like

```
Work_Order__c wo = new Work_Order__c();
wo.Est_Hours__c = 3;
insert wo;

vendor.Current_Work_Order__c = wo.Id;
update vendor;
```

Comment: what is `vendor` in your code? you instantiating the vendor object?

Answer (score -1):

you are trying to query your vendor base on a Work_Order__c Id??  no way. 
you should also bulkify your code - work with lists and define your queries more precisely ..

```
public List Work_Order__c>  woList    {get;set}
public List Vendor__c> vendorList    {get;set;}
public List Vendor__c> vendor2update = new List ();
```

vendorList = [Select Id From Vendor__c Where ??? ];
 woList = [Select Id From Work_Order__c Where ?? ];

```
    for (Vendor__c v:vendorList){
      for (Work_Order__c wo: woList) {
         v.Current_Work_Order__c = wo.Id;
         vendor2update.add(v);
    }
   try { update vendor2update; }
   catch (DMLExpection ex) {}
```